# Using underscore.js in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am trying to use keys function from underscore in node console as follows

```
$node
> require('./underscore.js')
...
> _.keys
[Function: keys]
> _.keys
undefined
```

Why does keys function disapper?
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_` is used by [Node REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features) to store the result of the last expression therefore after your initial call to [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) the `_` will be referencing the `keys` function. To avoid this you need to explicitly use a non-clashing name as a reference to underscore e.g.

```
$node
> _und = require('./underscore.js')
...
> _und.keys
[Function: keys]
> _und.keys
[Function: keys]
```